# Have a fixed <ImageBackground> that doesn't displace itself when I scroll

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, imagebackground

I want to have a background image that takes all the screen and stays static when I scroll.

I have this component in a React Native project:

```
<ImageBackground`     style={styles.backgroundImage}
 source={require('../assets/images/Fondo1b.jpg')}>
 ....
</ImageBackground>
```

It is wrapping another components and it has this style:

```
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height
  },
```

When I scroll up and down, it moves with the screen:
[GIF link](https://i.imgur.com/nRjXbEV.gif)

In here you can see how it displaces with the scroll.

I need it to stay static occuping the size of the screen, not moving when I scroll and not displacing my FAB (it's Native Base's FAB, it that helps...)
Any tips, please?

Comment: I believe what you’re looking for is `background-attachment: fixed`

Comment: It doen's work in React Native :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out. Need exactly this for React Native

https://medium.com/azimuth/adding-a-static-background-for-react-native-scrollview-79aa6b43e314

```
<ImageBackground style={styles.backgroundImage}/>  


  backgroundImage: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: -1
  },
```

Comment: Place your ScrollView element on top of ImageBackground. Also make its backgroundColor transparent

Comment: I'm out of class, but gonna try It tomorrow and let you know. Thanks!